Trace of a function and $L^\infty$ norm
Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $C= \lbrace(x, y): x\in\Omega, y\in [0, +\infty)\rbrace$.
Let $$X(C)=\left\lbrace u\in L^2(C): u|_{\partial\Omega\times [0, +\infty)}=0 \ \text{ and } \int_C |\nabla u|^2 dx dy <+\infty\right\rbrace$$.
For $u\in C(\Omega)$  define
$T:X(C)\to L^2(\Omega)$ be such that $T(u)=u(\cdot,0)$.
Assume that there is $k>0$ such that $||u||_{L^\infty(C)}\le k $.
Can we conclude that $||T(u)||_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\le k$?
I am interested in this because I am reading a proof in which it is stated that $u\in \mathcal C^{\alpha}(C)$ implies that $T(u)\in \mathcal C^\alpha(\Omega)$, so I am trying to get this through the norms, starting with the $L^\infty$ one.

Obviously if $u$ is continuous, then $|(Tu)(x)| = |u(x, 0)| \leq |u|_{L^{\infty}}$.

@Kakashi, I do not get it. Why is that true?

And what about if $u$ is only $L^\infty$?

It is true because $\lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R})}$ is the pointwise a.e. maximum

@HyperbolicPDEfriend could you please provide more details? (As an answer if yiu prefer). Also, shouldn't that be $|u|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$=

@HyperbolicPDEfriend I don't think it's true if only $u \in L^{\infty}$ because $|u|_{L^\infty}$ gives you no control over the values of $u$ on a subset of measure $0$.

This isn't the kind of problem where you need to use norm estimates. You have by definition that for $x \in \Omega$, $Tu(x) = u(x, 0)$. So if $u \in C^{0, \alpha}(C)$ then $Tu \in C^{0, \alpha}(\Omega)$ since $|Tu(x) - Tu(y)| = |u(x, 0) - u(y, 0)| \leq \|u\|_{C^{0, \alpha}}|x - y|^{\alpha}$.

Sayng that $Tu\in C^{0, \alpha}(\Omega)$ means that $Tu\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ as well. This means that I do have a control on the $L^\infty$ norm of $Tu$, isn't it?

yeah you have $|Tu|{L^{\infty}} = \sup{x \in \Omega}|Tu(x)| \leq |u|_{L^{\infty}}$

Kakashi, could you please explain the inequality $\sup_{x\in\Omega} |Tu(x)|\le |u|_{L^\infty (\Omega)}$?

For continuous functions, the $L^{\infty}$ norm equals the $\sup$ norm, so $\sup_{x \in \Omega}|Tu(x)| = \sup_{x \in \Omega}|u(x, 0)| \leq \sup_{(x, y) \in C}|u(x, y)| = |u|_{L^{\infty}}$.
